# Benelli 600i - Hanging Revs when decelerating and idle surge but fixes after restarting the motorcyle

Tags: motorcycle, idle, rpm

Having this strange issue lately where the RPM hangs when closing the throttle or drops slowly. The idle also surges to around 2k rpm. As weird as it sounds the problem seems to go away when I restart the motorcyle and the throttle is snappy with no hanging revs.
I am guessing the TPS sensor is malfunctioning.

P.S - The bike has new Fuel Pump,new fuel filter,new ignition coils,air filter, fuel injectors have been cleaned and throttle cable was recently lubricated.

It's getting somewhat annoying and would really appreciate any input.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you checked to ensure you don't have a vacuum leak?

Comment: Had recently got it serviced and the service guys did not mention any vacuum leaks upon enquiring them. I'll get it checked for the same.